# Nested lambda captures

Tags: c++11, lambda

When accessing variable a inside "run" lambda, I observe the address to be different than the 'a' in main. This is only happening with this kind of lambda nesting. Is this to be expected? I can only reproduce with this kind of non-trivial nesting.

I inspect the address with gdb inside the lambda as this->__a

Printing a inside the lambda with gdb yields garbage, while the lambda has the captured parameters inside the lambda object, that's why puzzles me that this->__a has different address than a:

```
(gdb) p &a
$5 = (unsigned int *) 0x7fffffffdce8
(gdb) p *this
$6 = {__a = @0x7fffffffdde8}
(gdb) p a
$7 = 4207233
(gdb) p this->__a
$8 = (unsigned int &) @0x7fffffffdde8: 2
```

When the lambda is not nested I recall observing the same address.

Currently seen this behavior in g++-4.5 (Debian 4.5.3-3) 4.5.3 and g++-4.6 (Debian 4.6.0-10) 4.6.1 20110526 (prerelease)

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned a = 0;
    vector<int> vi = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    auto run = [&](int& i) {
        // inside this lambda &a is not the same as the &a in the first line
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        a++;
        cout << "a: " << a << endl;

    };
    for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), [&](int& xi) {
        run(xi);
    });

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
}
```

I filled the following bugreport in a related to this question issue:
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49651

Comment: Behaves exactly as expected for me (GCC 4.6) -- what did you think would happen and what does happen?

Comment: Did you look the address with a debugger? if you just print &a inside the run lambda the result is what is expected, but that's not the real 'a' that is used by the lambda, which is this->__a

Comment: @piotr: and what happens if you print out the address or otherwise use it in the program, instead of insepcting it in the debugger? Values observed in the debugger do not count as observable side effects, and so, the compiler can pretty much change them freely as part of optimizations.

Comment: @Piotr: I didn't debug, I just observed the output which appeared to manipulate `a` exactly in the way I would expect. What exactly is your concern?

Comment: I'll research more and post my results.

Comment: I clarified with the debugger output. Certainly printing &a inside the lambda does what's expected. Printing this->__a inside the lambda without the debugger is not possible.

Comment: works exactly as expected, so there is no problem with implementation. whether a particular debugger has a bug or not, it's not a language issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is a bug. Lambdas are fairly new; maybe GDB doesn't support them very well. If the value inside the lambda, from the actual code (rather than the debugger) is correct, then it's probably a GDB bug, rather than a GCC bug.

Comment: @Nicol: did you read the bugreport I filled for GCC?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in gcc. It is fixed now.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49651

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple syllogism:

- Printing `&a` yields the correct value.
- Observing `this->__a` yields a different value.

ergo

- `this->__a` is not the same thing as `&a`

So how do we explain this? `this->__a` may be an object which contains a *description* of `a`, the compiler may have put any kind of metadata in there for debugging or any other purposes.